# insert multiple values from a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good day, fellow SQLers!  I am working to insert multiple values into a table, both tables are in different schemas.

```
INSERT INTO users.users (created_by, email, passwd) 
VALUES (
  (SELECT 
    customers.created_by,
    customers.email,
    'P455word'
   FROM customers.customers
   WHERE customers.tbl_id = (SELECT MAX(customers.tbl_id) FROM customers.customers)
    )
);
```

I am getting this error: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
Any suggestions for a work around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `values`:

```
INSERT INTO users.users (created_by, email, passwd) 
    SELECT customers.created_by, customers.email, 'P455word'
    FROM customers.customers
    WHERE customers.tbl_id = (SELECT MAX(customers.tbl_id) FROM customers.customers);
```

Assuming your intention is to only insert one row, you might consider:

```
INSERT INTO users.users (created_by, email, passwd) 
    SELECT c.created_by, c.email, 'P455word'
    FROM c.customers
    ORDER BY c.tbl_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```